# AWS Cloudformation: How to get a RestAPI name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

## Goal

Get the name for an API GW created within Cloudformation stack. The API Name is required if trying to get an API GW metric, since they exist `By Api Name`

### `.yaml` Example

```
TESTAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: 'test api'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
```

### Problem

If I call `!Ref TESTAPI`, I get the API ID, and if I call `!GetAtt TESTAPI.Name` the error is: "invalid resource attribute"

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html) don't show any return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the CloudFormation `RestApi` resource is modified, it will not provide the `Name` attribute.

### Workaround

Create a string [`Parameter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) to hold the string and enforce the API Name, which you can refer later with `!GetAtt APIName.Value`

#### YAML example

```
APIName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      AllowedPattern: "^[-a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"
      Type: String
      Value: "Some API name"
```